# Removing XML-Tags in nested SELECT-Statement from FOR XML PATH() in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I need to remove the xml-tags from the nested sql statement:

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (
        SELECT Mailbox
        FROM dbo.Mailbox
        WHERE UnitGroup IN (
            SELECT a.Groups
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT ID, GroupFC AS Groups
                FROM dbo.v_Pending

                UNION ALL

                SELECT DISTINCT ID, GroupBN AS Groups
                FROM dbo.v_Pending

                UNION ALL

                SELECT DISTINCT ID, GroupRM AS Groups
                FROM dbo.v_Pending
            ) AS a
            WHERE a.Groups IS NOT NULL
            AND a.ID = 12345
        )
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 0, ''
) AS Mails
```

I tried it with the statement `FOR XML PATH('')` but it doesn't work. Maybe someone knows the error. I always get the xml-tags -.-

Currently result looks like this:

```
<Mailbox>abc@xyz.com;</Mailbox>
<Mailbox>def@xyz.com;</Mailbox>
```

Comment: What do you want it to return?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem. I had to add in my nested SELECT-Statement an empty string `''`:

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (
        SELECT '' + Mailbox
        FROM dbo.Mailbox
        WHERE UnitGroup IN (
            SELECT a.Groups
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT ID, GroupFC AS Groups
                FROM dbo.v_Pending

                UNION ALL

                SELECT DISTINCT ID, GroupBN AS Groups
                FROM dbo.v_Pending

                UNION ALL

                SELECT DISTINCT ID, GroupRM AS Groups
                FROM dbo.v_Pending
            ) AS a
            WHERE a.Groups IS NOT NULL
            AND a.ID = 12345
        )
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 0, ''
) AS Mails
```